# mysql sorting by most votes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am having problem sorting joined mysql results, having two related tables:

Table users:

```
id, name
--------
1,  Alex
2,  John
```

Table votes:

```
user_id, vote
-------------
1,         1
1,         1
1,         1
1,        -1
1,        -1
2,         1
2,         1
2,         1
```

Alex have 1 vote score in summary
John have 3.
Therefore John will be first, Alex second.

How can i get users list ordered by sum of "vote" field on votes table ?
"vote" field are integer (can be 1,-1,0 or any other integer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this MySql query that uses GROUP BY, and aggregated function SUM:

```
SELECT name
FROM users inner join votes
     ON users.id = votes.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY SUM(vote) DESC
```

see it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/638bb/2).

Answer (score 1):

```
select users.* from users
left join 
(
 select user_id,SUM(vote) as sum_vote 
 from votes 
 group by user_id
) as v on users.id=v.user_id
order by v.sum_vote
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

`User.joins(:votes).sum('votes.vote', group: 'votes.user_id', order: 'sum_votes_vote')`

`sum_votes_vote` came from the alias that Rails gives to the sum.  You can also use

`User.joins(:votes).sum(:vote, group: 'votes.user_id', order: 'sum_vote')`

which will give the same result.  You can append `DESC` or `ASC` to `sum_vote` if needed.

Comment: does .sum will fetch results (ActiveRelation will become array/hash) ?

Comment: yes, the result will not be an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. You get a hash if you pass a `:group` option, you get an integer/float/decimal (depending on column type that you are trying to add) if not.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select u.name from users u inner join votes v on u.id=v.user_id  group by u.id order by sum(vote) desc
```